# Border-Radius for DIV element is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `-moz-border-radius:10px; 
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;`
properties of `DIV` element is not working in IE8, but this is working perfectly in Firefox and google chrome. Please provide me if you have any resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `-moz...` and `-webkit...` are properties for firefox and safari/chrome!

Also `border-radius` is a CSS3 property and IE8 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 property `border-radius` is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) in IE8.

If you can, I highly recommend taking a [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) approach with dealing with issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at PIE --  http://css3pie.com. It supports most CSS3 properties, like border-radius, and it works with IE7, IE8, and IE9. Does not tax CSS3 compliant browsers.

You can read more about it on the website, but essentially it works like this:

```
div#foo {
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```